# Why is Graphql data object only available outside the call function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, frontend, apollo

I am new to graphql and react so I can't figure out why the loaded data return object is only available outside the mutation post which produced the data. Could someone please explain this concept?

The data object immediately after the call here always returns undefined for some reason:

```html
const handleSubmit = async() => {
    try{  
      await addPerson({ variables: {  
        "name":Name,
        "title":Title,
        "imageURI":What } })
      ;
   
     console.log(data) // *** always undefined ***
     
    }
```

Somehow the data object is only available outside of the mutation query

```html
export const SubmitPage = () => {
  const [addPerson, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(Persons);
  const [addTask] = useMutation(Tasks);

  const [Name, setName] = useState<string>("");
  const [Title, setTitle] = useState<string>("");
  const [What, setWhat] = useState<string>("");

  
  
  if (loading) console.log("loading");
  if (error) console.log("error");
  
  console.log(data) // *** data only shows up here ***

  if (data === undefined){
    console.log("response data not loaded yet")
  }
  else{
    console.log(data.addPerson.id)

   
const handleSubmit = async() => {
    try{  
      await addPerson({ variables: {  
        "name":Name,
        "title":Title,
        "imageURI":What } })
      ;
   
     console.log(data) //always returns undefined
     
    }
    
    catch(e){console.log(e)}
  
  };

    
  return( <Container className = "submit-form">
          <Typography variant="h4">Submit Page</Typography>
          
        
          <Grid>
          First Name
          <TextField label = "required" value ={Name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}/>
          Title
          <TextField label = "required" value ={Title} onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}/>
          Some
          <TextField label = "required" value ={What} onChange={e => setWhat(e.target.value)}/>
          </Grid>
        
          <Button onClick ={handleSubmit} >submit</Button> 
          
          
          </Container>
)};
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with graphql, but the declaration of your variables / objects doesn't look correct. Unfortunately I'm not able to help you any further. Maybe I'm also wrong, cause I've no idea.

Comment: It seems like the answer is "because that is how things work." Why do you believe that `data` _should_ be set there, and what are you hoping to do with it?

Comment: Thanks I solved this will post reasoning later!

Answer (score 0):

console.log(data) data is undefined inside the function because graphql loading from a database is an asynchronous operation. The data hasn't loaded when this line is executed.

Since this the useQuery / useMutation is a hook it will reload the function so the data will be there next render (thus seen outside the function)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).